# Reveal file in Finder functionality for OS X

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I'm familiar with

```
explorer /select,/path/to/something
```

To open the folder that contains a file, with that file highlighted, in windows explorer.  Anybody know of a one liner (or one liner applescript) to do the same for OS X with the Finder?  Google search didn't seem to reveal much in the way of one liners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `open` command normally acts as if you double-clicked a file, but it has a `-R` flag to reveal the argument in finder. Therefore, you're looking for:

```
open -R /path/to/something
```

For further information, consult the open man page.

Answer (score 5):

Finder's AppleScript dictionary has a `reveal` command:

```
tell app "Finder" to reveal POSIX file "/private/etc"
```

But it doesn't bring Finder to the front or use your default view options for the created window.

This should additionally do both of those:

```
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    activate
    set selection to {}
    set target of window 1 to (POSIX file "/private/etc")
end tell
```